# asp.NET 2.0 Web Site Can't Access Classes in App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm having a problem accessing a class after deploying my website to a server.
Note that this is a Web *Site* not Web *Application*.The error is:

**Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Order' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

**Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433**

I've done a lot of googling and haven't been able to find anything that helps.

My code looks like this (I get the compiler error on the line declaring Order):

```
//Default.aspx.cs
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Order custOrder;
        ....etc
    }
}
```

In the App_Code folder I have Order.cs:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Order
    {
        ....etc
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that this works fine locally and in a dev environment.  When I move it to a qa environment, that's when I get that error.

I deploy by committing all the code to a subversion repository and then doing an export on the server machines.

I guess it could be some kind of namespace error, but I don't know why it would work on some machines and not others.

Any idea what could be different on a different server that might cause this?  All machines report the .net version as 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says, the error means that it couldn't find that type.

Possible causes:

1. A compilation error prevented the .cs files in your app_code folder from being compiled. When ASP.NET looks at the compiled code, it can't find the class you're looking for, thus the error.
2. The .cs files weren't deployed to app_code. Obviously if the source files aren't in the site, they can't be compiled.
3. A permissions issue is preventing the server from loading the .cs files.
4. One of your pages is incorrectly referencing the class - perhaps a typo in the .cs or the .aspx, a class moved to a new namespace or renamed, etc.

Essentially, the source couldn't be found, accessed or compiled.

Comment: 1 and 4 are unlikely since it compiles correctly on two other machines.  I'll double check that the folder is there, but I don't see why it wouldn't have copied the same way the aspx file did.  Ditto for permissions.

Comment: @Tavis Did this problem appear recently? Any server config changes (unlikely but worth asking)?

Comment: This is the first time it's been tried on that particular server.  My best guess is that it's been configured improperly, but I don't have access to it.  All I can do is request to have a folder uploaded to it.  Sort of narrows my options.  I was hoping someone might have seen something similar.

Comment: Finally got access to the server.  Was being deployed as a folder under a web site, not as a web site itself.

Comment: @Tavis that'll do it. Website projects are finicky in this regard. Ever consider moving to a web application project? Your life would be much, much easier.

Comment: @David Lively Wish I could.  Big Enterprise operation.  Took me forever to even get a look at the server.  Making those changes is way out of scope.  I also wish I wasn't running .net2.0 on a win2k machine :)

Comment: @Tavis I feel your pain. I finally got everyone to move the VS2010, .NET 4 and Win7 for development, but all of the servers are still on IIS6. Keeping configurations in sync isn't all that exciting.

Answer (score 18):

Right click the source file in App_Code and set its "Build Action" property to "Compile".

Comment: This fixed it for me after moving files manually into a new web application project.  The build action properties for each of the files in app_code were set to content instead of compile.

Comment: By default Visual Studio 2008 sets the build action to Content when adding CS files to App_Code. The default build action ought to be Compile. One would think CS files added to App_Code would clearly mean you want them to be compiled.

Comment: Yeah I things it's very strange especially when it's a pretty common task to re-use .cs files

Comment: It did the trick. It was set as Content when I moved the files to a web project. I was trying to get this to work for last 20 minutes or so. :)

Comment: I don't seem to have this option in an asp.net website project :(

Comment: @MatthewLock website projects in asp.net don't build. They are just interpreted so it doesn't make sense to have cs files in there. You need a web application project.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times the bin directory is ignored in SVN (for good reason) so what ends up happening is that locally (when debugging) VS takes care of creating the App_Code.dll for you. What you will need to do is check to see if the bin directory is deployed to your server machines.  If it isn't you have many ways to deploy your solution, by using deploy website, or ftp copy, etc.

Comment: I have no bin directory locally or on the remote machines.  I think this is a consequence of this being a web site, not web application so there is no build step.  The files in App_Code are compiled at runtime.  Maybe I'm mistaken here?

Comment: Is the App_Code folder being copied up to the servers?  this is the only thing that i can think of as to why you are getting a type not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Is the property Build Action set to Compile on your App_Code files ? It is not by default on Web Application Projects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying the .dll within your .aspx file?

Comment: As this is a website, I was under the impression that the files in App_Code are compiled at runtime and I don't need to do anything with dll's.  Can you clarify what you mean by deploying within my .aspx file?

Comment: You have to deploy the .aspx file to the application root and the .dll from the bin dir to the bin dir of the application root...

Comment: Refer to Szeliga's answer, he explains what I mean

Comment: No bin dir.  See Szeliga's answer