# Calling class from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am still new to ASP.net and I'm learning how to call classes.  I've looked around for tutorials, but not all are specific to ASP.net 4.0 so I'm not sure if I should apply them.

Right now, I am trying to connect to my SQL database.  My webconfig file has been set up with the connectionstring "dbConnectionString" and is working properly when I've tested it with GridViews.  What I'd like to do now is access the database from code behind.

I've seen some ways to accomplish this, but I'd like the most efficient, resuable way.  I've tried to adopt the answer listed here: [How to create sql connection with c# code behind, access the sql server then conditionally redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806166/how-to-create-sql-connection-with-c-sharp-code-behind-access-the-sql-server-the) however, I'm getting an error.

I am doing this with C# as a website, not a web application.  Here is my code behind for Login.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using SqlComm; // Is this how I connect to my class from this page????


public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            //no code written yet
        }
    }

}
```

My class in the App_Code folder, file name SQLComm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// SQL Query class
/// </summary>
public class SqlComm
{
    // Connection string
    static string DatabaseConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    // Execute sql command with no value to return
    public static void SqlExecute(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    // Execute SQL query and return a value
    public static object SqlReturn(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(PjSql.dbcs()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            object result = (object)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return result;
        }
    }

    // Retrieve an entire table or part of it
    public static DataTable SqlDataTable(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            DataTable TempTable = new DataTable();
            TempTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            return TempTable;
        }
    }

    // Execute a stored procedure with 1 parameter
    // Returning a value or just executing with no returns
    public static object SqlStoredProcedure1Param(string StoredProcedure, string PrmName1, object Param1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(PrmName1, Param1.ToString()));
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            object obj = new object();
            obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I haven't written any code to actually use the class yet, but the "using SQLComm;" line itself is giving me this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlComm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

As I'm still new, I'm unsure where to go from here.  I seem to have included everything contained in the answer on the page I linked above.  What else and I missing?

**Edit: I read this post regarding a similar issue: [asp.NET 2.0 Web Site Can't Access Classes in App_Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672262/asp-net-2-0-web-site-cant-access-classes-in-app-code) 
Could this be because I am doing a website and not a web application, so the App_Code folder is being handled differently when I FTP the files over?**

Comment: `using SqlComm;` shouldn't that be `using SqlDataClient`..?

Comment: Maybe you need to set the build action to compile in the .cs file in the App_Code folder. Apart from that you should then be able to access the class and it's methods directly.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter do I need to do that for a website, I thought that was only for web applications?  I've looked at the instructions on how to do that in Visual Web Developer and don't seem to have that option when I right click the file

Comment: @Cineno28: I must admit that i'm not really familiar with websites, so  that was just a guess.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter No problem, I appreciate the help! I've seen that option when working with applications, but I figured I'd start off with learning .net websites before diving fully into web applications.

Answer (score 1):

`using SQLComm` means you want to use the *namespace* `SqlComm`, which doesn't exist.  I think what you want is (somewhere in your codebehind):

```
DataTable dt = SqlComm.SqlDataTable(...)   // call one of the static methods.
```

Comment: @D Stanley Thank you for your help!  I've tried this line: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = SqlComm.SqlDataTable("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='demo'"); and now I'm getting an error that "SqlComm doesn't exist in the current context"

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to the project in which the `SqlComm` exists, if in a different project, and wrap your class with a namespace, because that's the way to do it.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan So it has to be within a namespace? From D Stanley's note I thought that since it wasn't withing a namespace I could call it directly?  I wrapped it in a namepace "SqlComm" and put "Using SqlComm" back in the codebehind but it's still giving me an error.  To answer your other question, yes it's in the same project

Answer (score 1):

You can call it directly.
Given your class has static methods only you'll call it like this:

```
SqlComm.SqlReturn("select * from table");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I've tried the above line returning to an object and I'm still getting an error saying that "CS0103: The name 'SqlComm' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I figured it out.  I had my App_Code folder within the subdirectory of my Aspx website, instead of in the root of the server.  I moved the folder to the root and now it's working.

I'd be interested in hearing any answers to my edit to my original post though.  Since I'm doing this as a website instead of a web application, are there any other issues I will need to keep in mind regarding using classes like this or other issues?  I've looked around but haven't seen many differences.

Thanks to everyone for you help!